# Need lexical context in eval for Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a string parser that takes input like "{x} + 20" and evaluates the lexical value of x with the sum of 20 and returns. So

```
var x = 10;
var new = eval("{x} + 20".replace("/\{(\w+\}/g", "$1"));
```

and here "new" should equal 30.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just do this:

```
var x = 10
var y = eval("x + 20")
```

No?

Comment: PS "new" is a reserved keyword so if you're getting errors it could be related to that.

Comment: Also he is feeding replace a string instead of a `RegExp` object, and even then the regex is invalid (missing a `')'`)